# MySQL: Extend a DATE table

Tags: mysql, database, calendar, mariadb

I work with a DATE table (a calendar) that I want to extend e.g. :

The monthly table **astreinte_mensu** runs from 12 Jul. 2018 to 12 Jul. 2019

But now I would like to extend it to 12 Jul. 2020, by keeping the data that has been already recorded.

**What I've already tried :**
Copy the entire database to a temporary one.
Recreate the DB.
Try to refill it unsuccessfully

How could this be done ? Have someone a better idea ?
Thank you in advance!

Here you have the structure of the table:

```
+------------+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| dateID     | Annee | Mois      | Personne1Nuit | Personne2Nuit | Personne1Jour | Personne2Jour |
+------------+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2018-07-12 |  2018 | juillet   |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2018-08-12 |  2018 | août      |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2018-09-12 |  2018 | septembre |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2018-10-12 |  2018 | octobre   |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2018-11-12 |  2018 | novembre  |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2018-12-12 |  2018 | décembre  |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2019-01-12 |  2019 | janvier   |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2019-02-12 |  2019 | février   |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2019-03-12 |  2019 | mars      |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2019-04-12 |  2019 | avril     |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2019-05-12 |  2019 | mai       |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2019-06-12 |  2019 | juin      |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
| 2019-07-12 |  2019 | juillet   |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |
+------------+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Create the copy:

```
CREATE TABLE testDB.astreinte_mensu AS (SELECT * FROM astreinte_mensu);
```

Drop the table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS astreinte_mensu;
```

Refill with the data by dateID: (Got a **Duplicate entry '0000-00-00' error**)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT dateID FROM testDB.astreinte_mensu WHERE MONTH(dateID) = MONTH(astreinte_mensu.dateID) AND YEAR(dateID) = YEAR(astreinte_mensu.dateID)) THEN
    SELECT Personne1Nuit FROM testDB.astreinte_mensu WHERE MONTH(dateID) = MONTH(testDB.astreinte_mensu.dateID) AND YEAR(dateID) = YEAR(testDB.astreinte_mensu.dateID);
    INSERT INTO astreinte_mensu (Personne1Nuit) SELECT Personne1Nuit FROM testDB.astreinte_mensu WHERE MONTH(dateID) = MONTH(testDB.astreinte_mensu.dateID) AND YEAR(dateID) = YEAR(testDB.astreinte_mensu.dateID);
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to insert new values?

INSERT INTO astreinte_mensu (dateID,Annee,Mois) values ('2019-08-12','2019','août')

INSERT INTO astreinte_mensu (dateID,Annee,Mois) values ('Your values','Your values','Your values')

Comment: Yeah it is definitively easier ! I must now find a way to delete the entries I no longer need, for which the date is past :) Thank you

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Please mark it as the answer and upvote if it helped you. Cheers! :)